# How do you choose the correct MOSFET for your project?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current

I am building an electric longboard. I am replicating this exact ESC [circuit by GreatScott](https://www.instructables.com/Make-Your-Own-Sensored-ESC/). The amount of voltage and current that will be going through my MOSFET's are 36V Max and 80A Max.

I need 3 N-channel MOSFETS and 3 P-channel MOSFETS. The N channel MOSFET GreatScott uses is rated for 55V and 49A, and the P-channel MOSFET is rated for 55V and 31A. Since I need a max amp rating of 80 amps I decided I should get some higher rated MOSFETS instead of using the same ones he uses.

I am thinking for the N-channel MOSFET of using an IRF3205 which is rated for 55V and 110A. I'm having a hard time finding a P-channel MOSFET that is able to handle these voltage and current ratings.

**Question:** Is the N-channel MOSFET I picked a good option? Do you have any suggestions on P-channel MOSFETS that would work? Any advice on picking the correct MOSFET's would be appreciated.

Comment: You also need to look at the gate characters. In this case you should be OK.

Comment: You can made a search at https://www.onsemi.com/products/discrete-power-modules/mosfets#products=fjI1MDIzMzl+dmFsdWV+MTF+LTIzNH4tMjIyfi0xODN+NDEwfjQyM340NDF+NDU4fjQ2NH40NzB+NTUzfjU1OH4=

Comment: AT 36 volt your driver chip will blow despite 55Volt fets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using matched pair of Pch and Nch FETS, **you should choose dual Nch Half Bridges rated for much more than your winding resistance stall current** in order to ease the temp rise from inevitable power loss. That will reduce the size of your heat-spreader which must have a very low thermal resistance like having a dozen massive CPU coolers with fans.  You will need to apply the thermodynamics of thermal resistance to estimate heat rise from accelerating to max speed with the maximum mass load.

You can also compare performance with low capacitance but higher saturation voltage IGBT's with FET gate drivers.  Due to the higher usable current density of IGBTs, it can usually handle 300% more current than a typical MOSFET it replaces. This means that a single IGBT device can replace multiple MOSFETs in parallel operation or any of the super-large single power MOSFETs that are available today

https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_IR2x33_IR2x35_DataSheet_v01_01_EN-1731357.pdf

http://www.irf.com/technical-info/designtp/dtwarp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the requirements.

For example, the basics for simple slow switching applications are:

- the max drain source voltage must never be exceeded (apply a safety factor)
- the gate to source voltage must never be exceeded
- the drain source resistance must meet your voltage drop requirement. It depends on Vgs.
- less trivial: the MOS must handle the current, but do not blindly follow the current capability for that. These are specified at a constant case temperature (Tc) or a constant ambiant temperature (Ta) with specific assumptions on the copper footprint (large copper pour on FR4 usually) - which are generally different from practical situations.

It is generally wise to make a quick thermal analysis based on a dissipation of RdsON*Id^2 that flows through the various thermal resistances you want to consider - typically junction-case + case-to-heatsink + heatsink-to-ambiant (which may depend on airflow), and maybe that across the copper to a constant temperature boundary. Only then can you check that the junction temperature is within reasonable margins of the absolute max.

Note that some transistors give you a Safe Operating Area (Vds vs Id) which includes the thermal limitation but still under specific conditions.

For higher speeds, the next key aspect to check is the gate capacitance that slows down the MOS opening or closing by forming a RC with the driver's output resistance.

There are many more things you may have to check but at this stage it's beyond the scope of a general question like that.